# Importing a Class into another in CSS

Tags: css, class

I am writing a short code to make a form visible when some one clicks on a button. So I have written down these css lines. But now I need to know how to import a class into another. The following is what I wrote.

```
   .upload {
    background-image: url(images/window.png);
    height: 261px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -163px;
    margin-top: -225px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 333px;
    visibility:hidden;
}

.click {
    /*I wanna import the class 'upload' here... 
    /*just like .upload:visibility:visible

}
```

Comment: You need something like LESS or SASS

Comment: May I ask, why you want that. You can add more than one class to an HTML element.

Comment: Your question isn't entirely clear to me... Could you show the part of your html that you want to alter so it's a more clear question?

Answer (score 1):

You can write like this:

```
.upload.click{
 visibility:visible;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<button value="submit" class="upload click"/>
```

Comment: This is aint what I wanted. Consider that you have a button. When you click on that button a form with a white panel as a BG becomes visible which was hidden before the click...

Comment: I am also saying the same thing you have to add the click class with JS when you click the button.